# Action Handlers Not Working on View itself

Tags: ember.js

Do action handlers not work directly on view instances?

Instead of attaching an action handler within the view, I want to attach it directly on the entire view itself.

Sample jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3wdG/

**UPDATE:**

My goal is to delegate to specific functions (undo, redo in this case) on the parentView. The reason I have the buttonView is because on click on each button, I want to do something to it, for example add a css class to it.

So in effect, I want all my buttons to add a class to themselves on click and then delegate to separate functions on the parent view.

Is this possible using this approach?

Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvkgk/

Comment: Where did you see this kind of syntax ? Why not directly use the `click` handler in the view ? Could you precise what is your goal here ? You want ember handlebars view helper support this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't think there is a built in ember way to do that, but check this jsfiddle, it seems work as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/xvkgk/8/

Comment: I suspected there was an easier or rather an Ember way to do this. The kind of syntax I was looking for was possible Ember.Button or a view extending that. I assumed you could do it with other views too.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to make a custom view subclass. You can then add a `click` function the subclass that will handle `click` events automatically.