# How can I make custom events that bubble through the view hierarchy?

Tags: ember.js

I have button views that are part of a set of Ember.js form helpers I wrote. E.g. MyAddressFormView has the following template:

```
{{#form}}
  {{textArea address}}
  {{submitButton}}
  {{cancelButton}}
{{/form}}
```

To handle the "Submit" button, I let the "submit" form event bubble, and handle it in the `submit` method of MyAddressFormView.

But how do I do the same for the "Cancel" button? For instance, is there any way I can trigger a custom "cancel form" event in a child view, let it bubble, and handle it in an ancestor view?

Comment: Could this more or less answer to your needs ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815100/action-handlers-not-working-on-view-itself/12817046#12817046

Comment: It would do as a stop-gap, but I'd perhaps end up with `{{cancelButton targetBinding="parentView.parentView"}}`. Having to know about the parentView seems like a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: Did you see the other example I put as comment ? Perhaps this is a better answer, as the event is bubbled, so the code does not have to change if you nest one level deeper. it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/xvkgk/22/

Comment: If you're interrested, I've given an other answer, perhaps it's more satifying for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027124/event-delegation-for-target/

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, sly - those are very creative solutions! For my app I've decided that it's probably cleanest to resort to calling methods (action handlers) on the controller and router for now. I wish there was a clean way to get bubbling custom events, but in the meantime, I'll try not to force Ember into doing something it's not meant to.

Comment: Agree Jo Liss, though I do my best to give answers, I always ask myself if they stick to "Ember.js way of life"... having a feedback from people like you is always great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest triggering a jQuery special event and registering the event with a mapping on your Ember app. For example:

```
Ember.Application.create({
  customEvents: {
    // key is the jquery event, value is the name used in views
    formcancel: 'formCancel'
  }
});
```

And in your cancelButton view:

```
click: function(evt){
  Ember.$().trigger('formcancel')
}
```

This will bubble in the same way that other mapped Ember DOM events do.

Comment: Relevant docs: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events

Comment: What is the `Em` ? Is that an alias for `Ember` ?

Comment: @carter Yes. `Em` is an alias of `Ember`. Updating my answer so as not to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Ember.ActionHandler bubbles events through its "target" property. It's possible to override Ember.View's target to let events bubble through parentViews by default.

Include this mixin first:

```
(function() {
    Ember.View.reopen({
        // Let actions bubble to parentView by default.
        target: function() {
            return this.get('parentView');
        }.property('parentView')
    });
})();
```

Then just send the event like you'd normally do:

```
tap: function() { this.send('someEvent'); }
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea to patch all views by default - you are breaking a core assumption of how ember views work and I would be astounded if this didn't make lots of things break