# Event delegation for target

Tags: ember.js

In the following code, my *click* events delegate and all three *'click'* handlers in my view hierarchy get fired.

However, I also want to fire *'edit'* in my entire view hierarchy. **'edit'** is simply the target of an element in my *'child'* view.

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view App.GrandparentView}}
    {{#view App.ParentView}}
        {{#view App.ChildView}}
           <span {{action "edit" target="view"}}>Click Me</span>
        {{/view}}    
    {{/view}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

​
**JavaScript**

```
App.GrandparentView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function() {
    console.log('Grandparent Click Fired!');
  },
  edit: function () {
   console.log('GrandParent edit fired');        
  }
});
App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function() {
    console.log('Parent Click Fired!');
  },
  edit: function () {
    console.log('Parent edit fired');        
  }

});
App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function() {
    console.log('Child Click Fired!');
  },
  edit: function () {
    console.log('Child edit fired');        
  }

});​
```

Is there no way to delegate the target handlers in the view hierarchy? What I **dont** want to do is this:

```
App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function() {
    console.log('Child Click Fired!');
  },
  edit: function () {
    console.log('Child edit fired');        
    this.get('parentView').edit(); //DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS.
  }
});​
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/xN2my/) as an example to test.

Comment: If you provide a JSFiddle, please provide one that actually operates. The point of providing a fiddle is not just to see code, it's to actually play around with it. It defeats the purpose if I have to set up Ember inside of the fiddle.

Comment: Absolutely, my bad. The point was always to provide a working jsFiddle. I played with the fiddle myself. For some weird reason, the resources got removed. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the same question you've posted about a week ago. As far as I can see, such feature is not implemented in ember. The event is propagated to the view hierarchy, but the action name is lost, and the default `click` handler is triggered.

The only workaround I found is to reopen the Ember.View class itself, and override the click handler like this:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  click: function(event){
    if(event.view !== this && this[event.actionName]){
        return this[event.actionName](event);
    }
  }
})
```

See the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/zZyCS/

Comment: I see what you have done here. I was expecting this to be supported.

Comment: Any thoughts on whether this should be naturally supported by Ember? @sly7_7

Comment: see this comment from @joliss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918112/how-can-i-make-custom-events-that-bubble-through-the-view-hierarchy#comment17706531_12918112