# Ember.js: Sending action to parent view

Tags: ember.js

I'm using [ember-easyForm](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easyForm) and I have a non-submit button in the form which I want the parent view to handle.

my_view.hbs:

```
{{#form-for model}}
  <button {{action "delete"}}>Delete</button>
{{/form-for}}
```

You used to be able to do:

```
<button {{action "delete" target="parentView"}}>Delete</button>
```

But it doesn't seem to work in the latest version of Ember.js. Is there any other way of passing the action to the parent view?

The following will get the form to handle the action but that's not what I want:

```
<button {{action "delete" target="view"}}>Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a bit more digging, I got the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815100/action-handlers-not-working-on-view-itself/12817046). So this is how you do it:

```
<button {{action "delete" target="view.parentView"}}>Delete</button>
```

Which seems to be a better implementation than target="parentView", as you now, I presume, target the parent view of the parent view.